# General question about finding the minimal polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose you're given a root $\alpha$ and asked to find the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$, where $F$ is some field. The usual strategy I've seen for solving these problems is to set $x=\alpha$ and then manipulate this expression to get a polynomial $f(x)$ for which $\alpha$ is a zero. Then, it suffices to show that $f(x)$ is irreducible.

My question is whether there are cases where you will follow this procedure and get a polynomial that is not irreducible. Are there any obvious examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might depend on how you "manipulate this expression".
For example, if $F = \mathbb Q$ and $\alpha = \exp(2 \pi i/n)$, you might well come up with the polynomial $x^n - 1$.  But this is not irreducible: the polynomial you want is the $n$'th cyclotomic polynomial.